# Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ be a convergent series such that $a_n \downarrow 0$. Prove that, $ \lim_{n\to \infty} na_n = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

This is my proof so far,

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. By CCC, there is $N > 0$, such that, if $n,m>N$, then $|\Sigma_{i=m+1}^n a_i| < \varepsilon$. We can drop the absolute values as $a_i \geq 0$, and, $a_{m+1}\geq a_{m+2}\geq ... \geq a_n$.

now I'm stuck.

Comment: The number of times this was already asked on the site defies the imagination.

Comment: Maybe you want to see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983651/let-x-n-downarrow-0-and-sum-x-n-to-s-then-n-cdot-x-n-to-0) question I opened some days ago.

Comment: I think that if there are more than two weeks without a post asking this question, the universe will implode...

Comment: @DonAntonio: let's hope for the continued incompetence of calculus students or their teachers! $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: @RobArthan Internet is an excellent excuse not to use those things called books...but if that really helps them I'm all for it.

Comment: I actually tried looking for this answer but I couldn't find it I apologize.