# Prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} na_n=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ be a convergent positive series, and
> satisfy $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$. Prove
> $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} na_n=0.$

First, we may consider applying Cauchy's condensation test. Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n a_{2^n}$ is convergent as well, which implies $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}2^n a_{2^n}=0$. Hence, there already exists a subsequence of $\{na_n\}$ convergent to zero. But how to go on ?

Comment: @Buraian Can you give a full proof please?

Comment: Cauchy's condensation works only if $(a_n)$ is non-increasing. – With that additional condition, a  proof is e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4603/42969 or here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1983651/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your correction. I forget that. We are not given the "non-increasing" condition, indeed.

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Answer (score 2):

This result is wrong.

#### Counter Example

For all $k \ge 0; 0 \le m \le 2^{k}-1$, define $a_{2^k+m}$ as follows:
$$ a_{2^k+m}= 2^{-k}.\max \left( 2^{-m\frac{k^2}{2^k} } ,2^{-1-(2^k-m)\frac{k^2}{2^k} }\right) $$
This defintion is nothing extraordinary if you look at the line graph of the log sequence $\left( \log(a_n), n \ge 1\right)$ . It is just a piecewise linear curves whose maximas are attained at points of form $2^k$.
Also, the slope of that graph becomes more flatter and eventually becomes a horizontal lines.( Because $\frac{k^2}{2^k} \rightarrow 0$ ).
And we can even check it by some simple algebraic arguments that:
$$ \lim \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}= 1$$
While we can check that :
$$ \sum_{ m \ge 0}^{2^k-1} a_{2^k+m} \le \left(2^{-k}+2^{-k-1} \right)\left( 
 \frac{ 1-2^{-k^2}}{1-2^{-k^2/2^k}} \right)$$
( replacing the max by the sum of each components)

$$ LHS \le 2.2^{-k}. \underbrace{ \frac{4.2^k}{ k^2 } }_{1-2^{-k^2/2^k} \ge \frac{k^2}{4.2^k}}.(1-2^{-k^2}) \le \frac{8}{k^2} $$
Thus $\sum_{n} a_n < \infty$
**However** , by definition
$$\limsup na_n=1$$

**Discussion**:

- There must be some kind of additional condition in order for that to be true.
- As shown in many previous topics, the condition of monotonicity is a pertinent choice. To me, that's conditional is somehow pretty tight...
- As I have shown in my counterexample above: a condition on the convergence rate of $ \limsup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} =1$ is  also crucial.

Comment: Can you give a simpler counterexample？

Comment: Perhaps there is a simpler one but it'll take time, and I already spent not so little time working on this problem.

Comment: I also did a survey on all presented solutions in the previous topics. The methods used in those solutions can be reused to relax the monotonicity. That is, if we have:
$$ \limsup \left( \frac{a_{n+1}}{n} \right)^n <e$$
In instead of the monotonicity, we are still able to imply the limit 
$$ \lim na_n =0$$
*Remark 1* : This is a condtion of type convergence rate.<br>
*Remark 2*  : The inequality is strict.<br>
*Remark 3* : IMHO, this condition is already tight. After all my work, I feel that I can provide a counterexample when that inequality is not strict.